# PsExec access denied

Tags: powershell

The username and password is correct but it shows 'Access is denied'. I try update registry as most article mention but no hope. Can someone help me to investigate this issue?

```
Program 'PsExec.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ psexec \\192.10.0.1 -u .\foo -p bar -h cmd "\\192.10.0 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ psexec \\192.10.0.1 -u .\foo -p bar -h cmd "\\192.10.0 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: This isn't a Posh issue. Can you run anything against that node?

Comment: The user needs to be a local admin of the target machine.

Comment: @Scepticalist it's a local admin of the target machine

Answer (score 0):

In my case `psexec` was block by the infra team...